# How to use media queries to fit the website to mobile view

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I am using media queries for the responsive website. But whenever the browser window size decreases the media queries will be applied according to the size. But the media query is not applied to the website whenever the browser size is set to mobile view. How to wrote those queries? this is my css and html .Whenever the is less than 760px the content should be margin right. How to do that?

```css
@media all screen and (min-width:410) and (max-width:760px) {
  .image2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: 1000%
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <h3 class="text1" style="margin-top: 30px; font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';font-size:60px;"> Multi Currency Wallet</h3> <br> <br>
  <div class="row text-center ">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="Assets/img/deyapay.png" class="image2" alt="Paris" style="width:20%; height:30%;"><br>
      <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';margin-right:20px">deyaCoin</h4>
      <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left;">
        Get Paid instantly. The moment you sell something is the moment you get paid.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="Assets/img/creditcard.png" class="image2" alt="New York" style="width: 25% ;height:30%;"><br>
      <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';">Credit/Debit</h4>
      <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left">
        we takes the user card details and process the payment transaction.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="Assets/img/bank.png" class="image2" alt="San Francisco" style="width:20%;height:30%;"><br>
      <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';margin-right:30px;">ACH</h4>
      <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left">
        We collect the bank details and process your payment in secure manner.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="Assets/img/group.png" alt="Paris" class="image2" style="width:25%; height:30%;"><br>
      <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed'; margin-left: 20px;">Share Expenses</h4>
      <p style="text-align:justify;margin-left: 38%;float:left;">
        Jack, Jane and John go on a skiing weekend together. Jack pays for the ski-hire;Jane pays the hotel; John pays for dinner.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img src="Assets/img/money.png" alt="Paris" class="image2" style="width:25%; height:30%;"><br>
      <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';margin-left: 10px">ReceiveMoney</h4>
      <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left;">
        You can request money among your family, friends, contacts, or split money among your contacts to receive money from.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <br><br>
```

Comment: you forgot to put `px` in `min-width:410`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot `px` in `min-width` and do not use `all`**

See fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/6180Lub2/

```css
    @media screen and (max-width:760px ) and (min-width:410px)  {
             .image2 {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            margin-right: 1000%
        }

          }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
          <h3 class = "text1" style = "margin-top: 30px; font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';font-size:60px;"> Multi Currency Wallet</h3> <br> <br>
          <div class="row text-center ">
             <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="Assets/img/deyapay.png" class = "image2" alt="Paris" 
                 style = "width:20%; height:30%;" ><br>
                 <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';margin-right:20px">deyaCoin</h4>
                <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left;" >  
                     Get Paid instantly.
                   The moment you sell something 
                     is the moment you get paid.</p>
              </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="Assets/img/creditcard.png" class = "image2" alt="New York" 
                     style = "width: 25% ;height:30%;" ><br>
                <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';">Credit/Debit</h4>
                <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left">  
                  we takes the user card details
                  and process the payment transaction.
                </p>

              </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="Assets/img/bank.png" class = "image2" alt="San Francisco" 
                style="width:20%;height:30%;"><br>
                <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';margin-right:30px;">ACH</h4>
                <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left">  
                We collect the bank details and
                process your payment in secure manner.</p>
              </div>
          </div> 
          <div class="row text-center">
             <div class = "col-sm-4">
               <img src="Assets/img/group.png"  alt="Paris" class = "image2" 
                 style = "width:25%; height:30%;" ><br>
                 <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed'; margin-left: 20px;">Share Expenses</h4>
                <p style="text-align:justify;margin-left: 38%;float:left;" >  
                  Jack, Jane and John go on a skiing 
                  weekend together. Jack pays for the
                  ski-hire;Jane pays the hotel;
                  John pays for dinner.</p>
              </div>
              <div class = "col-sm-4">
               <img src="Assets/img/money.png" alt="Paris"  class="image2" 
                 style = "width:25%; height:30%;" ><br>
                 <h4 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';margin-left: 10px">ReceiveMoney</h4>
                <p style="text-align:justify; margin-left: 38%;float:left;" >  
                  You can request money among 
                  your family, friends, contacts,
                  or split money among your contacts
                  to receive money from.</p>
              </div>
            </div>         
        </div> <br><br>
```

Comment: i placed the px but it didn't applied when width size > 420 px

Comment: This type of answer should be in comment, its just a typo mistake

Comment: i applied css style of width to image using media queries but it seems it doesn't applied to that image. i gave widthin % but there is no change in the width of image. i wrote like this : @media screen and (max-width:760px ) and (min-width:410px)  {
             
       
        .samyata{
           
           width:480px;
           height:480px;
          
        }}

Comment: This is my html :<div class="row" style="margin-left:7%" >
     <div class="col-sm-6"  class = "samyata">
     <img src="Assets/img/sam.png" class="samyata" hspace="30" style="width:28%;height:40%;float:left;">
    
       <h5 style="font-family: 'Fira Sans Condensed';text-align: left;">
         Get it the way you want </h5>
         <p style="text-align:left;font-size:13px;font-family: 'Dosis';">
         A new and effecient retail commerce platform
       </p></div></div>..  this ans help me alot